# Trying to fix some DRY event listeners

Tags: javascript, html

The biggest problem I have when I'm coding event listeners to change text fields to the value of an input field is that I have no idea how to do it without a separate event listener for each, and it looks very ugly. The `val` variables or any variants are the text fields, and the `aV`, `cV` or single letter variables are input fields.

```
aV.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        avaL.textContent = aV.value;
    };
});

cV.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        cvaL.textContent = cV.value;
    };
});

a.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        aVal.textContent = a.value;
    };
});

b.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        bVal.textContent = b.value;
    };
});

c.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev){
    if(ev.keyCode == 13){
        cVal.textContent = c.value;
    };
});
```

Comment: Can you post some of the HTML so we can see how the input fields and their associated elements relate to each other? Eg. the `aV` and `aval` elements?

Comment: Interested? If you do, I'm sure an even more elegant solution could be achieved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `forEach`:

```
var elems = [aV, cV, a, b, c];
var boxes = [avaL, cvaL, aVal, bVal, cVal];
elems.forEach((elem, idx) => {
    elem.addEventListener("keydown", function(ev) { 
        if (ev.keyCode == 13) {
            boxes[idx].textContent = elem.value;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What's `elem` and `idx`

Comment: They are the current element in the iteration (`elem`) and the index of that element (`idx`).